# Need help evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{ n^{kn} }{ (kn)! } , k\in N, k\neq 0 $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{ n^{kn} }{ (kn)! } , k\in N, k\neq 0 $

I need to study the limit as k changes. I think i should use ratio but i don't understand how to simplify and then study k, so I'd like to see all the steps.

Comment: hint: Stirling's approximation (Stirling's formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the ratio test you can see $$ \frac {(n+1)^{k(n+1)} )(kn)!} {(k(n+1))! (n)^{kn} } = (n+1)^k \frac{ (n+1)^{kn} } { (n)^{kn} }  \frac{(kn)! } {(kn+k)! }=  (1+\frac{1}{n})^n) ^{k} (n+1)^k \frac{1} {(kn +1)...(kn +k) } $$ so its limit will be $\frac{e^k} {k^k} $. Thus the sequence diverges for $k=1$ and $k=2$and converges for $ k\gt 2$

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes with the formulas, I'm quite new to this type of writing.

Comment: No probelm, thank you. Could you explain me how you get $\frac{e^k} {k^k}$ from the last step? I know how to get ${e^k}$ but don't understand how to have ${k^k}$.

Comment: If you calculate all the terms of numerator and denominator, you will have something like $\frac{n^k +something else} {(kn)^ k+ something else} $, I mean, a division of two polynomials with the same degree, k. So the limit of the fraction will be the ratio between them, that is k.

Answer (score 1):

We use Stirling's approximation for $n!$ at large $n$ $n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n$. Thus, as $n\to\infty$ we get:
$$
\frac{n^{kn}}{(kn)!}\to\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{k!}\exp[(k-1)n\ln n+n-0.5\ln n]
$$
as $ n\to\infty$ it is clear that the first term dominates. If $k-1>0$ or $k> 1$ the limit is $\infty$ if $k< 1$ the limit is $0$. If $k= 1$, the $ n$ term domintes and the limit is also  $\infty$